# java return specific value to shell script

Tags: java, shell

```
public class Test200 {
    public static void main (String args []) {
        System.out.println("David");
        System.out.println("Peter");
}
```

}

```
output=$(java Test200)
echo $output
```

I get the both value which are David Peter. Let say I only want "David" to be returned in shell script ? Any clue ? Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

You don't return `"David"` and `"Peter"`, you print them to `STDOUT`. So if you only want to print one of these, just remove the other `println` call.

You can only return integer values to the shell. This is done by [`System.exit(status)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#exit%28int%29).

Comment: But now i wish return a sql error code from the java  to shell , so i just need to code : System.exit(sql error code) ?

Answer (score 0):

Try using **`grep`** command so that it will return the expected value alone for multiple values use **`egrep`**

```
output=$(java Test200)
```

instead use

```
output=$(java Test200 | grep 'David')
```

But i didnt tested this code, it should work.

or try this

```
java Test200 >> outfile
```

all the SYSOUT will redirect to outfile base on that you can do te operation with external script.

Comment: This one is just an example, the output value will be different for everytimes.

Comment: of course your idea will not be worked. Let say the whole program have more than 20 of system.out.print? All will be printed out to the file ? it will be very messy already.